# What does <%= @something %> mean in a Java properties file?

Tags: java, grails, configuration-files

I'm looking at a Grails project that uses external configuration files. I have an external configuration file that's a Java properties file, and I don't know what this line does:

```
environment.name = <%= @envname %>
```

What does `<%= @envname %>` do, and where is the `@envname` property being set at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groovy dynamically creates getter method for all your fields that can be referenced as properties, The @ operator allows you to override this behavior and access the field directly

The following will groovy code in a gsp page.
       <% %>

so if you access

```
environment.name
```

in a gsp page. I believe it will load

```
<% @envname %>
```

and just pring out what envname is defined as.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't mean anything in a property file.  Or more accurately, it means the character string `"<%= @envname %>"`

It can only have a specific meaning in addition to that if ...

- the properties file is somehow being preprocessed by something before it is loaded,
- the properties file is being read by a custom properties file reader that understand that syntax,
- the properties file is being textually inserted into some other file rather than being loaded in the normal way, or
- the property value is being inserted into something else where that string is meaningful.

The syntax *looks like* a JSP construct ... but that could be a coincidence.

**UPDATE** - According to Nate Weldon's answer, this is a GSP construct.

---

For the record, the classic Java properties file syntax is specified [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29).  There is no mention of any special meaning for `<%=` or `@` or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Well the `<%= @envname %>` format is how you include Java code in a JSP file.

Comment: Right, but how does that make sense in a Java properties file?

Comment: Is the properties file being used in a JSP context. For example, in a JSP file are you asking for `environment.name`, which would return the `<%= @envname %>`, which would eval to a real value.

Comment: @WATTOStudios can you provide an example?